# margin: auto is not centering my div even though width is set

Tags: html, css

Okay, this bugs me, because it's such a small problem - but apparently I can't make it work.

I'm making a responsive/fluid website. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="InnerWrapper">
        stuff...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
html {
}
body {
    background: #f2f2f2; /*#f6f6f6;*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*MOBILE*/
@media (min-width: 200px) {
    #Wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        margin: 42px 0 0 0;
    }
        #InnerWrapper {
            width: 96%;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 2%;
        }
}
/*TABLET*/
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #Wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        margin: 42px 0 0 0;
    }
        #InnerWrapper {
            width: 96%;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 2%;
        }
}
/*PC*/
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    #Wrapper {
        width: 980px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 42px auto 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
        #InnerWrapper {
            width: 980px;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
}
```

So... when the browser-width is more than 980px the design should be fixed to 980px which is does. What it doesn't do is - centering!

How can I fix this. This bugs me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is `float: left`. The floating layout algorithm takes priority over margins and forces the element to the left (allowing content following it to bubble up beside it).

Don't float it when you want it centred.

Comment: Oh sorry... I forgot to remove this before posting this. I have removed the float: left. Still doesnt work.

Comment: The **first** rule of centering - *"Don't float it when you want it centered."*

Comment: @Quentin - I have. The code is updated and not working.

Comment: @Morten — The only time the wrapper isn't floated left is when the width is under 200px.

Comment: @Quentin - Okay.. I need to understand something. Isn't the last element overriding the others?

Comment: @Morten — The last media query doesn't mention the `float` property at all, so it doesn't override it. In order to override it, it has to give it a new value. CSS is Cascading.